# What fonts are compatible with T2A (Cyrillic) encoding?

Tags: fonts, font-encodings, cyrillic

I'm trying to figure out what fonts are compatible with T2A encoding - seems like there's no such a list known to Google.

I've identified that iwona and computer roman (default) are supported. However, attempts to use other fonts with either `\usepackage{lmodern}` or `\renewcommand*\rmdefault{phv}` in preamble result in a warning

> Font shape "T2A/lmr/m/n" undefined(Font) using "T2A/cmr/m/n" instead.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,draft]{book}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian, english]{babel}
\usepackage{iwona}
\begin{document}
Some meaningful text.

Какой-то осмысленный текст.
\end{document}
```

Fonts I've tried so far are: times new roman, garamond, helvetica, palatino.

Maybe I'm missing something, so I'd be happy to be pushed in the right direction.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Doing

```
locate /t2a | grep 'texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/.*\.fd$'
```

outputs, on my updated TeX Live

```
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/antt/t2aantt.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/antt/t2aanttc.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/antt/t2aanttl.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/antt/t2aanttlc.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cantarell/t2afca.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cm-lgc/t2afcm.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cm-lgc/t2afcs.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cm-lgc/t2afct.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/comfortaa/t2afco.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cyrillic/t2accr.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cyrillic/t2acmbr.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cyrillic/t2acmdh.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cyrillic/t2acmfib.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cyrillic/t2acmfr.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cyrillic/t2acmr.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cyrillic/t2acmss.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cyrillic/t2acmtl.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cyrillic/t2acmtt.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cyrillic/t2acmvtt.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cyrillic/t2alcmss.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cyrillic/t2alcmtt.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/droid/t2afdm.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/droid/t2afdr.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/droid/t2afds.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/iwona/t2aiwona.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/iwona/t2aiwonac.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/iwona/t2aiwonal.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/iwona/t2aiwonalc.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kurier/t2akurier.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kurier/t2akurierc.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kurier/t2akurierl.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kurier/t2akurierlc.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/opensans/t2afos.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/opensans/t2afosj.fd
```

With `/T2A` (which is an alternative), nothing is found.

1. `antt` refers to Antikwa Toruńska (`texdoc antt`)
2. `fca` refers to Cantarell (`texdoc cantarell`)
3. `afc` refers to something I can't find information about
4. `fco` refers to Comfortaa (`texdoc comfortaa`)
5. the `cyrillic` bundle consists of fonts based on the design of Computer Modern (the one used also if the main font family is Latin Modern)
6. `afd` refers to Droid (`texdoc droid`)
7. `iwona` refers to Iwona (`texdoc iwona`)
8. `kurier` refers to Kurier (`texdoc kurier`)
9. `fos` refers to Open Sans (`texdoc opensans`)

### Update (October 2014)

Other fonts have appeared since the last listing:

- gentium-tug: `\usepackage{gentium}`
- Heuristica: `\usepackage{Heuristica}`
- Erewhon: `\usepackage{erewhon}`

They have `.fd` files for T2A, T2B and T2C. The coverage for the last two is not complete, while Gentium seems to fully cover the three encodings.

### Update (June 2017)

There are new packages for Cyrillic:

- Tempora (based on Times New Roman): `\usepackage{tempora}`
- XCharter: `\usepackage{XCharter}`

## Update February 2018

With a current TeX Live, the command `locate '.fd' | grep '2017.*/[tT]2[aA]'` produces

```
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/antt/t2aantt.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/antt/t2aanttc.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/antt/t2aanttl.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/antt/t2aanttlc.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cantarell/t2afca.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cm-lgc/t2afcm.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cm-lgc/t2afcs.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cm-lgc/t2afct.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cmsrb/t2acmsrbr.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cmsrb/t2acmsrbs.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cmsrb/t2acmsrbt.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cochineal/T2ACochineal-LF.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cochineal/T2ACochineal-OsF.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cochineal/T2ACochineal-Sup.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cochineal/T2ACochineal-TLF.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cochineal/T2ACochineal-TOsF.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/comfortaa/t2afco.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cyrillic/t2accr.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cyrillic/t2acmbr.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cyrillic/t2acmdh.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cyrillic/t2acmfib.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cyrillic/t2acmfr.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cyrillic/t2acmr.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cyrillic/t2acmss.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cyrillic/t2acmtl.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cyrillic/t2acmtt.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cyrillic/t2acmvtt.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cyrillic/t2alcmss.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cyrillic/t2alcmtt.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/dejavu/T2ADejaVuSans-TLF.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/dejavu/T2ADejaVuSansCondensed-TLF.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/dejavu/T2ADejaVuSansMono-TLF.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/dejavu/T2ADejaVuSerif-TLF.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/dejavu/T2ADejaVuSerifCondensed-TLF.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/droid/t2afdm.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/droid/t2afdr.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/droid/t2afds.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/erewhon/T2Aerewhon-Dnom.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/erewhon/T2Aerewhon-Inf.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/erewhon/T2Aerewhon-LF.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/erewhon/T2Aerewhon-Numr.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/erewhon/T2Aerewhon-OsF.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/erewhon/T2Aerewhon-Sup.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/erewhon/T2Aerewhon-TLF.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/erewhon/T2Aerewhon-TOsF.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/gentium-tug/t2agentium.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/heuristica/T2AHeuristica-Inf.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/heuristica/T2AHeuristica-Sup.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/heuristica/T2AHeuristica-TLF.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/heuristica/T2AHeuristica-TOsF.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/iwona/t2aiwona.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/iwona/t2aiwonac.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/iwona/t2aiwonal.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/iwona/t2aiwonalc.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kurier/t2akurier.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kurier/t2akurierc.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kurier/t2akurierl.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kurier/t2akurierlc.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lato/T2Afla.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lato/T2Alato-LF.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lato/T2Alato-OsF.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lato/T2Alato-TLF.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lato/T2Alato-TOsF.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/libertinegc/T2ALinuxLibertineT-LF.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/libertinegc/T2ALinuxLibertineT-OsF.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/libertinegc/T2ALinuxLibertineT-TLF.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/libertinegc/T2ALinuxLibertineT-TOsF.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/miama/t2afmm.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nimbus15/T2ANimbusMono.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nimbus15/T2ANimbusMonoN.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nimbus15/T2ANimbusSans.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nimbus15/T2ANimbusSerif.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/opensans/t2afos.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/opensans/t2afosj.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/paratype/T2APTMono-TLF.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/paratype/T2APTSans-TLF.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/paratype/T2APTSansCaption-TLF.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/paratype/T2APTSansNarrow-TLF.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/paratype/T2APTSerif-TLF.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/paratype/T2APTSerifCaption-TLF.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tempora/t2atempora-tlf.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tempora/t2atempora-tosf.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcharter/T2AXCharter-Sup.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcharter/T2AXCharter-TLF.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcharter/T2AXCharter-TOsF.fd
```

Notable additions are PTSans, PTSerif, Linux Libertine, XCharter, Cochineal, DejaVu (Serif and Sans), Lato and Nimbus (Serif, Sans and Mono).

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I'll check what I have on my windows system

Comment: This fonts are great (especially droid, for me). Where can we find more, like this you wrote, compatible with cyrillic?

Comment: @Cortizol I'm afraid this is the complete list, for what concerns free fonts in TeX distributions.

Comment: @egreg OK. Can you say me why I can't load cantarell and comfortaa fonts? There is no problem with {iwona, kurier, dorid, anttor}. My code is:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{droid}

Comment: @Cortizol I can only think to the fact that those packages are not installed in your distribution. Are you on MiKTeX?

Comment: @egreg Yes. I set that MikTeX automatically update when it is necessary. And he actually was working something for cantarell font, but all was same in output PDF (standard [T2A] cyrillic)

Comment: @egreg And I search my computer and I have installed file cantarell.tpm in C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tpm\packages. Just saying.

Comment: There is now also `heuristica` and `erewhon`. `gentium-tug` also looks to support T2A. (Do you know why there are `.fd` files in the `doc` directory under `texlive-ru`?)

Comment: @cfr They seem to provide shapes for the `lmr` and `lmss` families (using the same fonts for `cmr` and `cmss`).

Comment: There are "Public Types of Rus­sian Fed­er­a­tion". Aviable in 
[`paratype` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/paratype).

Comment: What about DejaVu?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Thanks for the prompt, see the update.

Comment: Excellent commitment by @egreg to update the answer. Having just returned to some work from around 2016, the "tempora" tip solved my problem immediately.

Answer (score 4):

Cyrillic fonts for legacy LaTeX engines come with TeXLive and MiKTeX in `LH` (Metafont) and `cm-super` (PostScript)  bundles. MiKTeX installs `LH` fonts automatically on-demand, but you need to install `cm-super` manually. `Once installed, cm-super` fonts are loaded automatically when you produce either PS of PDF document, you don't need to call any package.

Most Metafont and PostSript font bundles (garamond, helvetica, palatino, e.t.c.) do not have Cyrillic letters.

Most OpenType fonts nowadays have Cyrillic letters. When using XeTeX or LuaTeX, you can try first `cm-unicode` fonts which come with TeXLive and MiKTeX.

Comment: I did install cm-super and got nice bilingual output with cmr font. The point was, however, to find out what flexibility t2a allows with minimal efforts of modifying preamble. And thank you for heads up on OpenType, I'll try them out, too.