# African letters in latex

Tags: symbols, languages, font-encodings, tipa

I am trying to put the following letter: `ɖ` in my latex file. I thought, I could use maybe `$\textdtail$`, but it doesn't work.

My preamble contains already

`\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, so I tried also to add to it `T4`. In result, the file is compiling and not executing anything. Then, I also tried to use the `tipa` package, but this simply does not work (I read somewhere that the last update was there in 2004, so that should be then understandable). If anyone has a trick how to insert this one letter into my text, I would welcome any suggestions.

Comment: Do you have a font containing these african letters on your system?

Comment: There are T4-encoded fonts, but only in bitmap form. Using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and a font containing the required glyphs would be much better.

Comment: Seems there is an extensive answer here:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304284/adding-complex-phonetic-symbols-to-latex

Comment: I want to add only one letter into my latex file. The indicated links are not solivng my problem. I tested it before posting the question. I don't understand why T1 and T4 do not work out together in the ```fontenc```, which would solve my problem. None of the packages like tipa, t4phonet...help.

Comment: I don't think you should change the encoding to T4. You are using a wrong command. `\textrtaild` is the correct command. Loading package `tipa` and using this command shall work. You can alternatively choose to use the shortcut. i.e. `\textipa{\:d}`.

Comment: Also you don't need math-mode for `tipa` commands. Remove the dollars.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for replying to my question. In fact, I solved the problem already a while ago, and it's almost exactly as you said. I have these packages in my LaTeX doc

```\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{tipa}```
And yes, it is correct what you are suggesting. I used ```\textipa{\:d}```  and it solved my problem.