# Which fonts support Cyrillic letters in TexLive?

Tags: fonts, cyrillic

TeXLive installs a lot of fonts. How can I know which of them support Cyrillic letters?

Comment: Did you see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114587/what-fonts-are-compatible-with-t2a-encoding?

Comment: @egreg I did. I just did not know that "T2A encoding" means "Cyrillic".

Comment: I added the word to the title. Can we close this question as duplicate?

Comment: Yes, I think we can. This question is not going to be *deleted*, but just *closed*, am I right?

Comment: No, it won't be deleted. People finding it will be pointed to the other one.

Answer (score 5):

I don't have a general solution which works for all font types supported by
TeX. Here's a script which searches a given directory for OpenType files and
displays the ones supporting the Cyrillic script. It uses [otfinfo](https://github.com/kohler/lcdf-typetools) ([otfinfo - man page](http://www.lcdf.org/type/otfinfo.1.html))

```
#!/bin/sh

#####
#
# Finds fonts that support a particular script
#
# Usage: font-script-search <directory>
#
#####

script='Cyrillic'

find "$1" -type f -name "*.otf" |
  while read file; do
    if otfinfo --scripts "$file" 2>/dev/null | grep "$script" >/dev/null; then
      otfinfo --postscript-name "$file"
    fi
  done | sort

exit 0
```