# Where can I find a list of supported fonts in Bulgarian, along with examples

Tags: fonts, pdftex

I am using `pdflatex` to write the rules of a simple game. The game is in Bulgarian. Here is the relevant part of the preamble:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside,openany]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[bulgarian]{babel}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
```

It works nice. Now I would want to use a more artistic font. [This](http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/macros/latex/doc/encguide.pdf) is the best I have been able to google ,and it does not match what I am looking for.

I need a list of supported fonts, plus short examples of each font, so I can choose a font and apply it to my document. Also a short instruction on how to apply it.

Comment: Related: [What fonts are compatible with T2A (Cyrillic) encoding?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114587/what-fonts-are-compatible-with-t2a-cyrillic-encoding)

Comment: What is the difference between your question and the question you link to in your comment?

Comment: @Sverre, 1) I am using a different encoding (without much understanding) and 2) I have no idea how to use the list of fonts to generate a page of samples, so that I can visually choose one.

Comment: You haven't specified any font encoding in your MWE at all, so if you're using a different encoding than ``T2A``, what are you using? (And why wouldn't you use ``T2A``?)

Comment: If your question is "how can I compile a document with the ``T2A`` fonts listed in the linked answer?", then please ask that (it's what I've answered below). If you're asking for a list of supported fonts, then your question is already answered by the linked answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a list of available `T2A` fonts with Cyrillic glyphs [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114598/9077). You can test them and choose the one you like best. Here's an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{droid} % <- one of the fonts with T2A encoding

\begin{document}
\noindent А а   Б б     В в     Г г     Д д     Е е     Ж ж     З з     И и     Й й\\
К к     Л л     М м     Н н     О о     П п     Р р     С с     Т т     У у\\
Ф ф     Х х     Ц ц     Ч ч     Ш ш     Щ щ     Ъ ъ     Ь ь     Ю ю     Я я
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Are there really no more fonts for installation? After compiling to a `.pdf`, the viewing machine does not need to have the font installed, right?

Comment: @Vorac I don't know what you mean by "no more fonts for installation". egreg mentions 9 font families in the answer we've linked to, and he says that's the complete list of free fonts included in latex distributions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complementary list of fonts that can be used with pdfLaTeX/XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX, that are not mentioned in the above link:

**Sans serif fonts**: `Cabin`, `Linux Biolinum`, `MyriadPro`.

**Serif fonts**: `Heuristica` and `Erewhon` (based on Adobe Utopia), `ebgaramond`, `Xcharter` (based on Bitstream Charter), `Linux Libertine`, `MinionPro`.

All these font are available in Opentype format (Minion Pro and Myriad Pro come with Adobe Reader) and can be very easily used for text with Xe/LuaLaTeX and `fontspec`.

Among theses fonts, only `Heuristica`, `Erewhon`, `MinionPro`nand `MyriadPro` can be used with pdfLaTeX for cyrillic glyphs.

**Edit**: The above-mentioned link now also points to `Heuristica` and `Erewhon`.

A demo with Heuristica and Erewhon (I couldn't make my old version of MinionPro work, although the relevant.fd files exist):

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    %\usepackage{heuristica} % <- one of the fonts with T2A encoding
    \parindent = 0pt

    \begin{document}
    \fontfamily{Heuristica-TOsF}\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont
    \textbf{Heuristica: }
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9\\
    \fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont
    \noindent А а Б б В в Г г Д д Е е Ж ж З з И и Й й\\
    К к Л л М м Н н О о П п Р р С с Т т У у\\
    Ф ф Х х Ц ц Ч ч Ш ш Щ щ Ъ ъ Ь ь Ю ю Я я\\[3ex]
    {\itshape А а Б б В в Г г Д д Е е Ж ж З з И и Й й\\
    К к Л л М м Н н О о П п Р р С с Т т У у\\
    Ф ф Х х Ц ц Ч ч Ш ш Щ щ Ъ ъ Ь ь Ю ю Я я\\}

    \vskip 1cm
    \fontfamily{erewhon-TOsF}\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont
    \textbf{Erewhon: }0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9\\
    \fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont
    \noindent А а Б б В в Г г Д д Е е Ж ж З з И и Й й\\
    К к Л л М м Н н О о П п Р р С с Т т У у\\
    Ф ф Х х Ц ц Ч ч Ш ш Щ щ Ъ ъ Ь ь Ю ю Я я\\[3ex]
    {\itshape А а Б б В в Г г Д д Е е Ж ж З з И и Й й\\
    К к Л л М м Н н О о П п Р р С с Т т У у\\
    Ф ф Х х Ц ц Ч ч Ш ш Щ щ Ъ ъ Ь ь Ю ю Я я\\}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with most of these fonts, but I am familiar with ``libertine``. It does not have any Cyrillic glyphs (i.e. no ``T2A`` encoding).

Comment: @Sverre: The Opentype version has Cyrillic, Greek (monotoniko and polytoniko), Basic Hebrew, and can be used with Xe/LuaLaTeX (not tested, but I don't see why it wouldn't work). I'm surprised no one did the job for T2A and LGR encodings!

Comment: Sure, but you actually wrote "fonts that can be used with LaTeX", and the OP did ask for fonts to use with ``pdflatex``. I think the list of ``.ttf`` and ``.otf`` fonts that have Cyrillic glyphs would be humongous. EDIT: And I would like to say "ditto" to your remark about the lacking ``T2A`` and ``LGR`` encodings for the ``libertine`` package.

Comment: @Sverre: I've just checked what can work with pdfLaTeX (much less!) and I'll add that. What's funny is that the rather recent `ebgaramond` has cyrillic and greek glyphs, that cannot be used with pdfLaTeX, except… the greek letters for maths.

Comment: Well I know that the maintainers of the ``libertine`` package are using pre-existing conversion tools to get from ``.otf`` fonts to ``.tfm`` fonts, and I believe those tools don't include conversions to ``T2A`` and ``LGR``. My guess would be that the same is the case for ``ebgaramond``.

Comment: If they are the LCDF Type Tools, they were used for MinionPro and MyriadPro, though (with special scripts of their own maybe).

Comment: I can't see fd files for Cyrillic encodings for Cabin, Biolinum, EB Garamond, Libertine and XCharter. The question asks for `pdflatex`.

Comment: @egreg/ Yes, I've updated my answer to add the list of those fonts that don't require Xe/LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Note that the relevant fonts - that is, those which can be used with pdfTeX - **are** now included in the linked question, along with `gentium-tug`.

Comment: @cfr:  Ok. I think my answer can remain, as there is a demo. But I'll ention the change. However the link soen't mention Minion Pro nor Myriad Pro — perhaps because it requires some work from the user?

Comment: I take it that egreg's answer there is limited to fonts which are usable with (pdf)LaTeX **and** in TeX Live. (Since that's the basis of the search - the TEXMFLOCAL tree is not searched.) So those are additional here, I think. (The same would go if, for example, `getnonfreefonts` installed fonts which supported Cyrillic - they would also be excluded from that list.) Note, though, that support is likely version specific. My version of Minion supports Cyrillic but my version of Myriad does not appear to.

Comment: @cfr: As to me , my version of Minion (at least 12 years old!) is supposed to support Cyrillic  — I  have fd's, tfm's, vf's but no pfb's. I suppose I missed something on installing the package. Strangely enough, I have nothing for Greek, , although the Opentype font, although the Opentype font has both monotoniko and polytoniko glyphs.

Comment: I have Greek definition files for MinionPro. Very limited for MyriadPro, though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17618/discussion-between-bernard-and-cfr).