# Currvita: cirillic and old style figures + right align item labels

Tags: horizontal-alignment, oldstylenums, currvita

I have this document with [currvita](https://ctan.org/pkg/currvita) package:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{cfr-lm}
\usepackage{currvita}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=3cm, top=3cm]{geometry}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage[overload]{textcase}
\newcommand*{\ac}[1]{\mbox{#1}}
\usepackage[unicode, hidelinks]{hyperref}
\tolerance=600
\begin{document}
\begin{cv}
    {1234567890}
    \begin{cvlist}{Interests}
        \item[2018] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pulvinar, lorem vel hendrerit convallis, lorem enim semper metus, ac imperdiet justo nisl eu lorem.
        \item[2017 — 2018] Лорем ипсум долор сит амет, ут иус цопиосае улламцорпер цонцлудатуряуе, яуи партем малуиссет интеллегат не.
    \end{cvlist}
\end{cv}
\end{document}
\endinput
```

[image]

I want to achieve two things: align the labels of the items to the right, and be able to use Russian alphabet and old style figures at the same time with the default font. The result should be something like this:

[image]Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: The `cfr-lm` fonts don't support Cyrillic.

Comment: Thanks @egreg; it can be a different font. The important thing would be to be able to use Cirillic and old style figures. But I cant do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only a few fonts supporting oldstyle figures in Cyrillic:

- Lato (sans serif)
- Erewhon
- Heuristica (essentially the same as Erewhon)
- XCharter

For the right alignment, you can patch the `\cvlist` macro.

Here is with Erewhon.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\usepackage{currvita}
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=3cm, top=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[osf]{erewhon}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[overload]{textcase}
\usepackage{regexpatch}

\usepackage[unicode, hidelinks]{hyperref}

\newcommand*{\ac}[1]{\mbox{#1}}

%% right alignment
\tracingxpatches
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\cvlist}{##1\hfill}{\hfill##1}{}{\ddt}
\makeatother

%\tolerance=600

\begin{document}
\begin{cv}

1234567890

\begin{cvlist}{Interests}

\item[2018] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pulvinar, lorem vel hendrerit convallis, lorem enim semper metus, ac imperdiet justo nisl eu lorem.

\item[2017 — 2018] Лорем ипсум долор сит амет, ут иус цопиосае улламцорпер цонцлудатуряуе, яуи партем малуиссет интеллегат не.

\end{cvlist}

\end{cv}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `\usepackage[osf]{XCharter}` the output is

[image]

With `\usepackage[default,oldstyle]{lato}` the output is

[image]

You have more choices for fonts if you switch to XeLaTeX.

Comment: Thanks @egreg; do you know where can I find a list of LaTeX cirillic fonts? If I switch to XeLaTeX, will I be able to use this currvita template?

Comment: @Nikita For a list of fonts, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114587/what-fonts-are-compatible-with-t2a-cyrillic-encoding/114598 and, yes, you can use `currvita` with XeLaTeX