# xelatex not showing Russian characters

Tags: fonts, xetex, cyrillic

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian, english]{babel}
\usepackage{droid}
\begin{document}
Some meaningful text.

Какой-то осмысленный текст.
\end{document}
```

When I run:

```
$ xelatex temp.tex
```

It shows this:

[image]

The problem is missing Russian glyphs in the font. I can use the Arian font and it will work:

```
\setmainfont{Arial Unicode MS}
```

But I don't like how it looks. Is it possible to use some Latex fonts instead? I read this discussion: [What fonts are compatible with T2A (Cyrillic) encoding?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114587/what-fonts-are-compatible-with-t2a-cyrillic-encoding), and saw that the author said "This fonts are great (especially droid, for me).". I tried to use droid package, but it doesn't work for me.

How to use the fonts with cyrillic support, shipped with TeX Live in xelatex?

**Update**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian, english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[default]{droidserif}
\usepackage[defaultsans]{droidsans}
\begin{document}
Some meaningful text.

Какой-то осмысленный текст.
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}` should not be used with xelatex. If you want to use xelatex use fontspec and `\setmainfont`. If you don't like Arial find another one.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer "If you don't like Arial find another one." - is it possible to use fonts shipped with Latex or only those installed in my system?

Comment: You can use  all fonts in fonts/opentype and fonts/truetype in your tex system, but I don't know which of them support cyrillic. You will have to check.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer egreg in his answer gives a listing of fonts. He mentions droid package. How to use them? ``\usepackage{droid}` doesn't work.

Comment: Hm. This package is not completly bugfree, droidmono seems to be missing. Try `\usepackage[default]{droidserif}\usepackage[defaultsans]{droidsans}` and report the error to the maintainer.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I updated the question. It still uses computer modern font and doesn't show the Russian text. Can you reproduce it on your machine? Can you give an answer with example of the working code?

Comment: Also I saw an advice to use `cm-unicode` fonts. But how to make xelatex use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how to do it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[russian, english]{babel}

\babelfont{rm}{Droid Serif}
\babelfont{sf}{Droid Sans}

\begin{document}

Some meaningful text.

Какой-то осмысленный текст.

\end{document}
```

See the `babel` manual for further details, because you may need to switch the language somehow with the Russian text.

[image]

Comment: It it possible to use Computer modern font in TeXLive 2020 out of the box? I had to install it manually from font squirrel.

Comment: Then this worked: `\setmainfont{CMU Concrete}`.

Comment: The equivalents to Computer Modern are `CMU Serif` and `CMU Sans Serif`.

Comment: I meant: do I need to install Computer modern family manually or it is somehow shipped with TeXLive?

Answer (score 2):

**don't use `\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}` with xelatex**

This here should work

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[default]{droidserif}
\usepackage[defaultsans]{droidsans}
\begin{document}
Какой-то осмысленный текст.
\sffamily 

Какой-то осмысленный текст.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nope, it gave me an empty pdf. What can be wrong? Using TeX Live 2018.

Comment: LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/fdr/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 4.

Comment: Then your system is too old. I have texlive 2020.

Comment: I installed TexLive 2020, now your code works. But is it possible to use computer modern like font? I like it.