How to obtain Cyrillic letters with polyglossia and main font TeX Gyre Pagella?
I use LuaLaTeX with
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\CMcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\CMcal}{bold}{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\CMbfcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}

to facilitate Unicode. But this does not combine well with my need to obtain Russian fonts via the polyglossia package, as I tried with:
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{german,russian,greek}

On account of the information in the second paragraph of Section 4: Font set up in the documentation to the polyglossia package, it appears that there should be a roundabout way to obtain the Russian fonts. How should I go about to obtain them?
Here is an MWE which is intended to illustrate my problem:
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{amsmath}  % loaded automatically by 'unicode-math'
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{cancel}
%\usepackage{fontspec} % loaded automatically by 'unicode-math'

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{russian,greek}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\CMcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\CMcal}{bold}{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\CMbfcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}

\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Book.otf}[range={cal, bfcal}]
%\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}[range=]

\setsansfont{Noto Sans}
\setmonofont{Noto Sans Mono}

\newfontfamily{\fcyc}{cyklop}
\newfontfamily{\falg}{AlgolRevived}[Scale=1.5,Color=red]
\newfontfamily{\fsong}{FandolSong}
\newfontfamily{\QTBrushStroke}{QTBrushStroke}

\begin{document}

test

гчйкгчй

γηκηασδκλφ

\begin{russian}
гчйкгчй
\end{russian}   
    
\end{document}


Pick a font that has cyrillic eg `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia} \setdefaultlanguage{english} \setotherlanguages{russian,greek}
\setmainfont{LinLibertine_R.otf}
\begin{document}
test
гчйкгчй
γηκηασδκλφ
\begin{russian} гчйкгчй \end{russian}
\end{document}`

@DavidCarlisle I need the math set up for the proper document where I use TeX Gyre Pagella to obtain desired mathematics characters.

@DavidCarlisle Let me quote from section 4 on Font set up  in the documentation of polyglossia,  which I mentioned: "For instance, if the default font defined by \setmainfont does not support Greek, then one can define the font used to display Greek with: \newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek,⟨…⟩]{⟨font⟩}.

"that's the whole point of minimal examples, omitting things not needed for the question" My question concerns how to obtain Russian fonts in the presence of TeX Gyre Pagella as main font. It may not be a minimal question, but it is a real question.

there is a babel version here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/540249/1090 you could use babel or I assume polyglossia has something similar, but it is simpler to use a font that has all the chanracters you need, as I show above then you don't need to switch font at all in the main text.

so that quote is your answer, you can use linlibertine or any other font that has cyrillic as the font in the definition of \russianfont if that's what you want to do,

\newfontfamily\russianfont[Script=Russian]{linlibertine}?

That gave me: Package fontspec Error: The font "linlibertine" cannot be found. \begin

you can use the filename as I showed above \newfontfamily\russianfont{LinLibertine_R.otf}

@DavidCarlisle Thanks! That worked for  \begin{russian} гчйкгчй \end{russian}, which is sufficient. :) !

Yes it won't fix Cyrillic outside declared russian, for that you would need to do as I suggested originally, change the main font, which is simpler and would give a more consistent document, but it's your choice ....

@DavidCarlisle In my situation it is satisfactory with the solution as it now is, with a special declaration needed for the Russian. Please write an answer for your solution to be on the record.

The TeX Gyre fonts don't support Cyrillic and have only partial support for Greek.
You can define a Times-based font for them, for instance Tempora that's distributed with TeX Live.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{cancel}
%\usepackage{fontspec} % loaded automatically by 'unicode-math'

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{russian,greek}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\CMcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\CMcal}{bold}{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\CMbfcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfont}{Tempora}
\newfontfamily{\greekfont}{Tempora}

\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Book.otf}[range={cal, bfcal}]
%\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}[range=]

\setsansfont{Noto Sans}
\setmonofont{Noto Sans Mono}

%\newfontfamily{\fcyc}{cyklop}
%\newfontfamily{\falg}{AlgolRevived}[Scale=1.5,Color=red]
%\newfontfamily{\fsong}{FandolSong}
%\newfontfamily{\QTBrushStroke}{QTBrushStroke}

\begin{document}

test

\begin{greek}
γηκηασδκλφ
\end{greek}

\begin{russian}
гчйкгчй
\end{russian}   
    
\end{document}



You need to pick a suitable text font, i.e., one that provides Cyrillic characters. As you've (re)discovered, TeX Gyre Pagella is not such a font. I suggest you give EB Garamond a try; it's one of many candidate Garalde font packages.

\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{amsmath}  % loaded automatically by 'unicode-math'
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{cancel}
%\usepackage{fontspec} % loaded automatically by 'unicode-math'

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{russian,greek}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\CMcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\CMcal}{bold}{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\CMbfcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}

\setmainfont{EB Garamond} % or some other suitable Garalde

\setmathfont{XITS Math}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Book.otf}[range={cal, bfcal},Scale=MatchLowercase]
%\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}[range=]

\setsansfont{Noto Sans}
\setmonofont{Noto Sans Mono}

\newfontfamily{\fcyc}{cyklop}
\newfontfamily{\falg}{AlgolRevived}[Scale=1.5,Color=red]
\newfontfamily{\fsong}{FandolSong}
\newfontfamily{\QTBrushStroke}{QTBrushStroke}

\begin{document}

test

гчйкгчй

\begin{russian}
гчйкгчй
\end{russian}   
    
γηκηασδκλφ

\end{document}


With relation to the original requirement for a pure Unicode
multilingual string with several scripts, i.e., without explicit markup, there are several approaches.
A different font
Replace TeX Gyre Pagella with a Palatino-like font like URW
Palladio, which provides Cyrillic and Greek (you must download and install it). This will show the correct characters, but specific font features and hyphenation won’t be activated. I don’t use polyglossia and I haven’t tested, but I think it should work.
combofont
With this package fonts can be combined. Pick a font you like and read the manual (sorry, again I don’t use combofont).
With babel
If switching to babel (which fully supports LuaLaTeX) is an option, you can choose different fonts and languages for different scripts. In this example I’ll use TeX Gyre Pagella as the main font and URW Palladio for Cyrillic and Greek (the font name is somewhat weird). Font features and hyphenation are activated, too.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{cancel}

% === Start Babel setup ===
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\babelprovide[import, onchar=ids fonts]{russian}
\babelprovide[import, onchar=ids fonts]{greek}
\babelfont{rm}{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\babelfont[*cyrillic, *greek]{rm}{P052} % = URW Palladio
% === End Babel setup ===

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\CMcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\CMcal}{bold}{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\CMbfcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}

\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Book.otf}[range={cal, bfcal}]

\setsansfont{Noto Sans}
\setmonofont{Noto Sans Mono}

\begin{document}

\hsize=1pt

test гчйкгчй γηκηασδκλφ --- \textit{test гчйкгчй γηκηασδκλφ}
    
\end{document}


(Of course, you can also set Palladio as the main font.)
If you want to stick to TeXLive fonts, you can set something like (only
the relevant part):
% === Start Babel setup ===
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\babelprovide[import, onchar=ids fonts]{russian}
\babelprovide[import, onchar=ids fonts]{greek}
\babelfont{rm}{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\babelfont[*cyrillic, *greek]{rm}{Tempora}
% === End Babel setup ===


Your original example loads FandonSong. You can add Chinese in a
similar way:
% === Start Babel setup ===
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\babelprovide[import, onchar=ids fonts]{russian}
\babelprovide[import, onchar=ids fonts]{greek}
\babelprovide[import, onchar=ids fonts]{chinese}
\babelfont{rm}{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\babelfont[*cyrillic, *greek]{rm}{Tempora}
\babelfont[chinese]{rm}{FandolSong}
% === End Babel setup ===

With the document body:
test гчйкгчй γηκηασδκλφ 中文 --- \textit{test гчйкгчй γηκηασδκλφ}

you get:

