# \babelfont doesn't work

Tags: fonts, babel, languages, cyrillic

I am trying to typeset a document with multiple languages, and I need to use a different font for one of the languages because of the lack of boldface for said language in the global font.

I tried to do the following

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[serbianc,french,english]{babel}
\babelfont{rm}{Linguistics Pro}
\babelfont[Language=serbian]{tt}{FreeSerif}

\begin{document}
\Serbianc{Hello, \texttt\Huge{Поздрав}!}
\end{document}
```

However, i get an "*undefined control sequence*" error.
I have tried to run the example from the babel documentation, Section 1.14, and I still received the same error.
I have no idea what is going on.

Is there a way to either load \babelfont, or to do the thing that I need in any other way?

Comment: `\babelfont[serbianc]{tt}{FreeSerif}` Don't load `fontenc` nor `inputenc`.

Comment: I assume you're using pdfLaTeX, you need LuaLaTex or XeLaTeX as your compiler for it to work.

Comment: You should load a `\babelfont{tt}` before `\babelfont[serbian]{tt}`.

Comment: @eliasf Indeed I am using pdfLaTeX.
Is it possible to do this without passing to a different compiler?
I have a huge document which cannot be compiled with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

Comment: @egreg I don't understand what that means.

Comment: @Davislor That doesn't work.

Comment: @Kolja Your `\babelfont` instruction is wrong: it should be `\babelfont[serbianc]{tt}{FreeSerif}`.

Comment: Added as answer as code won't show up nicely.

Comment: @egreg I also tried \babelfont[serbianc]{tt}{FreeSerif}, and it gave me the same error -- the \babelfont command is undefined.

Comment: `\texttt\Huge{Поздрав}` is the same as `\texttt{\Huge}{Поздрав}`. You might want to use `\texttt{\Huge{Поздрав}}`

Comment: @cgnieder I used many combinations. But even just \texttt{Поздрав} doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I had the same issue recently where I was unable to change compiler from pdfLaTeX I did the following for **Greek** text:

```
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}

% This is my main font
\usepackage{mlmodern}

% Switch back to Computer Modern for Greek
\usepackage{substitutefont}
\substitutefont{LGR}{\rmdefault}{cmr}
```

For Serbian you would need to find a **T2A** compatible font that would let you make it bold and not an OpenType as this won't work with pdfLaTeX.

**EDIT**

The following MWE produces what you want I think:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[serbianc,english]{babel}

\usepackage{substitutefont}
\substitutefont{T2A}{\ttdefault}{iwona}

\begin{document}
\Serbianc{Hello, \texttt{\Huge\textbf{Поздрав!}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The key lies in using a font supporting T2A encoding (here **iwona** is used), have a look at this:

[What fonts are compatible with T2A (Cyrillic) encoding?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114587/what-fonts-are-compatible-with-t2a-cyrillic-encoding)

Comment: What is \rmdefault? I am trying to apply the same fix to my code, but I have problems.
It keeps using T1 for serbian instead of T2A, and I get "command ... unavailable in T1"
Also \serbianc is an undefined control sequence, but this is a command from the babel serbianc package.
And everything is recompiled in a different font now, serbian is even used where it shouldn't be (outside of serbian chapter).

Answer (score 3):

This works with the last version of `babel` (2022/02/26 3.73)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[serbianc,french,english]{babel}

\babelfont{rm}{Linguistics Pro}
\babelfont[serbianc]{tt}{FreeSerif}

\begin{document}

\Serbianc{Hello, \texttt{\Huge Поздрав}!}

\end{document}
```

Note that `\texttt\Huge` does nothing at all.

[image]