# Adding russian to \usepackage[english]{babel} changes text to bold. How to get rid of that?

Tags: beamer, babel

This is the mwe of the problem I have in Beamer. If I only use the "english" option in babel, everything is fine, if I add "russian", the text becomes bold. It only seems to occur with /tiny text This is an unwanted outcome. How to get rid of it?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}

\begin{document}
\tiny bold text?
\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems that this is a bug in cm-super font collection. It provides all fonts from optical size 5pt. Original CM fonts provides sans serif from 8pt, so sfss0500 (from cm-super) is generated by a specific way and it is generated badly. You can look by fontforge that the font  sfss0500.pfb is bad. And `\tiny` in LaTeX selects the font at this small size. When you don't select russian in babel then cm-super font collection is not used.

Comment: @wondering Do you need to use computer modern font? Would using another font be an option?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Yes, using another font would be an option. How would the solution look like?

Comment: You could try e.g. `\usepackage[default]{opensans}` if you like to stick with pdflatex or see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114587/what-fonts-are-compatible-with-t2a-cyrillic-encoding for more options. If switching to xelatex or lualatex, you have more options.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thank you, this is a solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not set on using using computer modern font, you could switch to some other font, e.g.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}

\usepackage[default]{opensans}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\tiny bold text?

Видимое свечение чистых жидкостей под действием $\gamma$-радиации
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

(see [What fonts are compatible with T2A (Cyrillic) encoding?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114587/what-fonts-are-compatible-with-t2a-cyrillic-encoding) for more fonts which support Cyrillic)

Comment: As the problem seem to be caused by a bug, I guess this solution can be accepted as an answer, or what is the policy? Also I wonder if one could somehow just "unbold" the text by e.g. the \normalfont command. I seems not to work, though.